# Google+ : Multiple +1 on same page, different content

Tags: google-plus

I've tried to find an answer to this (both in the dev docs and here), but with no luck.

The "+1 button" works fine on normal pages (where there's just the single +1). But I have a page with multiple entities (to use the terms of Drupal: A View displaying multiple nodes) where I'd like to add "share buttons". So far I've added Twitter and Facebook.
Twitter is the simplest as it just takes the string you give it..
Facebook takes an url, but you can specify your own url.
When I try to specify my own url for +1 I get this Error:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://one80.seasites.se/whats-up from frame with URL https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/hover?hl=sv&url=http%3A%2F%2Fone80.seasites.se%2Fwhats-up%2Fl%25C3%25B6rdag&t=1342724634133&source=widget&isSet=false&referer=http%3A%2F%2Fone80.seasites.se%2Fwhats-up&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fgapi%2F__features__%2Frt%3Dj%2Fver%3Dr4LFRxx-_oY.sv.%2Fsv%3D1%2Fam%3D!ZCfx2q5v6YmYvWjcTQ%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAItRSTNI50TT3SY8R9klRLc_1sBJ5_Rp3g#id=I3_1342724634541&parent=http%3A%2F%2Fone80.seasites.se&rpctoken=619983104&_methods=mouseEvent%2CtrackingEvent%2ConVisibilityChanged%2C_onopen%2C_ready%2C_onclose%2CcloseOrHideThisBubble%2C_close%2C_open%2C_resizeMe%2C_renderstart. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
 rs=AItRSTOQ10u7fGwgD-LqzsOa-fsgdlhDCg:173
ec.a.v rs=AItRSTOQ10u7fGwgD-LqzsOa-fsgdlhDCg:173
xh rs=AItRSTOQ10u7fGwgD-LqzsOa-fsgdlhDCg:203
q.get rs=AItRSTOQ10u7fGwgD-LqzsOa-fsgdlhDCg:211
ec.w rs=AItRSTOQ10u7fGwgD-LqzsOa-fsgdlhDCg:173
Rh rs=AItRSTOQ10u7fGwgD-LqzsOa-fsgdlhDCg:208
q.w rs=AItRSTOQ10u7fGwgD-LqzsOa-fsgdlhDCg:220
Rb rs=AItRSTOQ10u7fGwgD-LqzsOa-fsgdlhDCg:30
Xg rs=AItRSTOQ10u7fGwgD-LqzsOa-fsgdlhDCg:187
```

(anonymous function) rs=AItRSTOQ10u7fGwgD-LqzsOa-fsgdlhDCg:226

To explain why I want to use separate URL:
every node is something like an event, every node has it's own url (which contains an image and text/info). So when you click Like (for FB) it gets the title, info & image and includes it in the post (So it says "What's up - Gathering", instead of a generic "What's up" and no/the same image).
I'd like to accomplish the same with G+.

Is there a way to accomplish this for G+?? Have I missed something??

I guess one way to do this is by using an iframe for each of the nodes and pull in a special version of the "node page" with just the g+-button. But that's a pretty nasty hack (and not that fun to set up).

Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're seeing is actually due to an issue in Chrome. The +1 button should automatically recover.

You can explicitly specify target pages by using the `href` [attribute](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#plusonetag-parametershttps://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#plusonetag-parameters). Your markup will look like this in practice:

```
<g:plusone href="http://example.com/targeturl"></g:plusone>
```

Or like this with HTML5 syntax:

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-href="http://example.com/targeturl"></div>
```

If these don't work, can you share a link to a page where you're seeing it not work? I can take a look :)

Comment: This is the code I use:

` <div class="g-plusone-wrap">
 <div class="g-plusone" data-annotation="none" data-size="tall" data-href="<?php echo $url; ?>" style="float: right"></div>
 </div>`

The site is here: [link](http://one80.seasites.se/whats-up)  (the URL given to +1 is printed to the left)

Comment: Thanks for the link!  It looks like your target URLs respond with an HTTP 302 redirect, no Location and a response body.  If you're using a 302 redirect, it must contain a location header with the redirect target URL.

Comment: Thank you!! :?)
It had totally slipped my mind that I had a redirect there! 
The "node-page" is supposed to redirect users to the "compilation page", but I had an exception for FB (checking for the FB User-Agent), I now managed to check for the G+ bot too (using the HTTP_X_GOOG_SOURCE header) and now it works perfectely! :?D

Comment: is it possible to reference an id in the target url as well? ie, http://mywebsite.com/index1.html#section5

and would the id make up part of the +1 count?